# Print the matched and unmatched column with pattern

Tags: scripts, text-processing

I have two files f1.txt and f2.txt. I need to compare both files and print the matching coloums as well print the unmatched columns with "not found" pattern.

f1:

```
hari:1.2.3.4/32
abc:3.4.5.6/24
bcd:8.9.10.11/34
```

f2:

```
1.2.3.4/32
3.4.5.6/24
8.9.10.11/34
10.12.34.0/22
1.4.5.7/34
```

desired Output:

```
hari:1.2.3.4/32
abc:3.4.5.6/24
bcd:8.9.10.11/34
not found:10.12.34.0/22
not found:1.4.5.7/34
```

could anyone please help to get the desired output.

Thanks

Comment: So f1 contains lines of the pattern `name:ip-slice` and f2 contains lines only consisting of `ip-slice`. And the output shall be again a file like f1 but with all additional lines from f2 and the prefix `not found:` added?

Comment: And can we assume that all ip slices in f1 are also in f2? Or what would the result need to be if not?

Answer (score 4):

You could use awk:

```bash
$ awk -F':' -vOFS=':' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print $1 in a?a[$1]:"not found",$1}' file1 file2
hari:1.2.3.4/32
abc:3.4.5.6/24
bcd:8.9.10.11/34
not found:10.12.34.0/22
not found:1.4.5.7/34
```

In a more readable format:

```bash
awk -F':' -vOFS=':' 'NR == FNR { # For the first file (file1)
                        a[$2] = $1 # store the first token in an array 
                                   # using the second token as the key
                        next       # skip to the next record
                     }
                     {  # For all lines of file 2
                        print $1 in a ? a[$1] : "not found" , $1 # print the desired result
                     }' file1 file2
```

Comment: @user2175455 If one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

Although your `f2` does not appear to be strictly ordered, `join` seems to work<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ join -t\: -12 -21 -a2 -e 'not found' -o1.1,0 f1 f2
hari:1.2.3.4/32
abc:3.4.5.6/24
bcd:8.9.10.11/34
not found:10.12.34.0/22
not found:1.4.5.7/34
```

With real data, you may need to pre-sort:

```
$ join -t\: -12 -21 -a2 -e 'not found' -o1.1,0 <(sort -t\: -k2,2 f1) <(sort -t\: -k1,1 f2) | sort
abc:3.4.5.6/24
bcd:8.9.10.11/34
hari:1.2.3.4/32
not found:10.12.34.0/22
not found:1.4.5.7/34
```

<sup>1</sup> perhaps because the *matchable* lines are sorted?

Comment: +1 Nice answer, Why is the colon (`:`) escaped thought? On my system is seems to work even without the escape...

Comment: Good point - just habit I guess, `:` does have special meaning in bash (it's a no-op - you'll sometimes see it used as such e.g. `: | paste - somefile` or `while :` in place of `while true`)